# Insertar el valor de una variable de JS a un atributo de HTML

Tags: javascript

### Tengo una variable con información:

```js
var info = prompt('Cual es tu valor');
```

La información que contiene la variable `info`, yo quiero pasarla al atributo de una etiqueta de **HTML5** que es `<img src='hola.jpg' alt='info' />`. Si se fija bien, quiero pasarle lo que contenga la variable **info** al atributo `alt` de la etiqueta **img**

El problema es que no logro hacer que funcione, ya que me muestra tal cual el nombre de la variable y no me imprime la información que contiene la variable, solo me imprime el nombre de la variable.

Intente hacer un `<img src='hola.jpg' alt='${info}' />`, pero el resultado que me muestra en el atributo **alt** es: `<img src='hola.jpg' alt='${info}' />` y no me imprime lo que el usuario ha agregado en la variable **info**

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor agrega el HTML y la definición de `cuerpo` que hace falta en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso una opción para lo que pides. Serviría para cualquier atributo que se te ocurra (nuevo, habitual como `alt` o uno inventado por ti), y como dice Federico convendría al menos poner un id o una(s) clase(s) a la imagen para después utilizarla cuando accedes a ella desde JS...

```
var info = prompt('Cual es tu valor?'),
    elemento = document.getElementById('imagen');
elemento.setAttribute('alt',info);
```

Comment: No me funciona, me salta un error de sintaxis: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')`

Comment: Braylin, ¿has puesto el atributo id a la imagen en el html? Asegúrate de eso. 
Por supuesto, hay cabida para mejorar el código, como comprobar si existe un elemento con ese Id antes de utilizarlo, etc. Pero quería ilustrar, más que nada, la resolución directa del asunto. En cualquier caso, haz esa comprobación

Answer (score 1):

Podrías agrgarle una `ìd` a la imagen:

```html
<img id='imagen' src='hola.jpg'>
```

Y luego desde el JS puedes cambiar el atributo `alt` así:

```js
var info = prompt('Cual es tu valor');
document.getElementById('imagen').alt = info;
```